# Segmentation fault in Dynamic Programming Problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a problem to solve which requires to find the minimum number of prime digits to form a number which is equal to the given number N. I choose dynamic programming for this problem but it gets Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) Message.

```
long long sumOfOneDigitPrime(long long n)
{
    vector<long long> arr;
    long long i;
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        arr.push_back(100000000000LL);
    }
    arr[0] = arr[2] = arr[3] = arr[5] = arr[7] = 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(i >= 2)
        {
            arr[i] = min(arr[i], 1+arr[i-2]);
        }
        if(i >= 3)
        {
            arr[i] = min(arr[i], 1+arr[i-3]);
        }
        if(i >= 5)
        {
            arr[i] = min(arr[i], 1+arr[i-5]);
        }
        if(i >= 7)
        {
            arr[i] = min(arr[i], 1+arr[i-7]);
        }
    }
    if(arr[n] == 100000000000LL)
        return -1;
    else
        return arr[n];
}
```

As you can see that the algorithms here is clear but I don't know why it gets Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) here. Before I use any indexes, I check it first.

Comment: How big is `n`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm As you can see that n is ``long long`` so I assume that n can be <=10^15

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm However, my program gets coredumped even when n is 19652

Comment: Which is way bigger than the stack space available.  `a` will need to be a `std::vector`, not a local array.

Comment: Also note that `long long arr[n+1];` is a Variable Length Array (VLA), which is part of C and is supported by some C++ compilers but is not part of standard C++.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I still get error for larger number, for example 11460819. How do I solve it?

Comment: @HoangNam [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d364f02ba44bbccd).

Comment: Why are you still pursuing this approach when `n` can be up to 10^15? Think about the complexity of your algorithm before you implement it so that you don't waste time attempting stuff that will never work.

Comment: Which line triggers the segmentation fault? Could you add a wrapper `main` function to make this a [mre]?

Comment: *"Before I use any indexes, I check it first."* -- this is not true if `n < 7`. Admittedly this does not explain a segmentation fault when `n` is 19652.

Comment: Here's the the solution: `a[7] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2}; return n == 1 ? -1 : n / 7 + a[n % 7];` Proof is left as an exercise for the reader. The basic idea is that you take as many 7's as you can. Then you do some casework on all the possible remainders and you can prove that the optimal way to form each remainder is the same no matter how many 7's you used. Note that if you have a remainder of 1 you need to remove one 7 so that you can form an 8 using 2 numbers.